# HTML QuickBlox API

Tags: html, database, quickblox

I am used to android development in eclipse and I would like to create a website.

I have done a lot of work on it > [Textile_24](http://www.TEXTILE-eng.tk)

I want to put "sign up, sign in, forgot password" in my HTML website .
Thanks in advance .

Here is the code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>TEXTILE"24"</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style_whmcs-blue.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/slicebox.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/custom.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/skins/blue.css">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="Wrapper">
            <div id="Wrapper_Content">
                <div id="Container">
                    <header>
                        <div id="Header">
                            <div class="Logo"></div>
                            <div class="Social_Icon">
                                <ul>
                                    <li class="facebook"><a href="#" target="_blank" title="فيسبوك"></a></li>
                                    <li class="twitter"><a href="#" target="_blank" title="تويتر"></a></li>
                                    <li class="youtube"><a href="#" target="_blank" title="يوتيوب"></a></li>
                                    <li class="rss"><a href="#" target="_blank" title="rss"></a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                            <!--/Social_Icon-->
                            <div class="Live_Support"><a href="#"><img src="images/Live_Support.jpg" alt=""></a></div>
                            <nav>
                                <div class="Menu">
                                    <div class="Menu_right"><a href="#"></a></div>
                                    <ul>
                                        <li><a href="#">أكـــــاديميات</a>
                                            <ul>
                                                <li><a href="#">الدراسات السودانية </a></li>
                                                <li><a href="#">الفيزياء</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="#">الجبر الخطي</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="#">اللغة العربية</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="#">اللغة الانجليزية</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="#">ميكانيكا الهندسة</a></li>
                                            </ul>
                                        </li>
                                        <li><a href="#">إجتماعيــــات</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">ثقافـــيات</a></li>
<li><a href="#">الرياضــة</a></li>


                                        <li><a href="#">عن الدفعة</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">عن هندسة النسيج</a></li>

                                        <li><a href="#">إتصل بنا</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                    <div class="Menu_left"><a href="#">تقديم إقتراح</a></div>
                                </div>
                            </nav>
                            <!--/Menu--> 
                        </div>
                    </header>
                    <!--/Header-->
                    <div id="Body">
                        <div id="Content">
                            <div id="Slider">
                                <div class="Slider">
                                    <ul id="sb-slider" class="sb-slider">
                                        <li><a href="#"><img src="images/slider/slider_1.jpg" alt=""></a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#"><img src="images/slider/slider_2.jpg" alt=""></a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#"><img src="images/slider/slider_3.jpg" alt=""></a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#"><img src="images/slider/slider_4.jpg" alt=""></a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#"><img src="images/slider/slider_5.jpg" alt=""></a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                                <!--/slider-->
                                <div id="nav-dots" class="nav-dots"> <span class="nav-dot-current"></span> <span></span> <span></span> <span></span> <span></span></div>
                                <div class="slider_shadow"></div>
                            </div>
                            <!--/Slider-->
                            <div id="Our_Services">
                                <div class="Our_Services">
                                    <ul>
                                        <li class="how_share"> <a href="#"></a>
                                            <div class="img"></div>
                                            <h2>خدمات الموقع</h2>
                                            <p>يعتبر الموقع الإلكتروني وسيلة من الوسائل السهلة لتوصيل المعلومات بصورة رسمية</p>
                                        </li>
                                        <li class="how_win"> <a href="#"></a>
                                            <div class="img"></div>
                                            <h2>التصميم</h2>
                                            <p>التصميم هو عامل اساسي فى نجاح اي موقع ,قدم لنا الاقتراحات المناسبة عت طريق "تقديم اقتراح" .</p>
                                        </li>
                                        <li class="how_adv"> <a href="#"></a>
                                            <div class="img"></div>
                                            <h2>افكار </h2>
                                            <p>ساعدنا وقدم لنا افكارك لنكون في مقدمة المواقع العربية </p>
                                        </li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <!--/Services-->


                        </div>
                        <!--/Content-->
                        <div id="Sidebar">
                            <div class="Widget">
                                <h2 class="login">دخول طلاب النسيج <span>-</span></h2>
                                <div class="Widget_Login">
                                </div>
                                <!--/Widget_Login--> 
                            </div>
                            <!--/Widget-->
                            <div class="Widget">
                                <h2 class="links">TX-DEV <span>-</span></h2>
                                <div class="Widget_Links">
                                    <ul>
                                        <li><a href="#">أجدد العروض</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">طلب موقع </a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">IOS طلب تطبيق اندرويد او</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">التعليمي TX مركز</a></li>

                                        <li><a href="#">اتصل بنا</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                                <!--/Widget_Links--> 
                            </div>
                            <!--/Widget-->
                            <div class="Widget">
                                <h2 class="likes">صفحتنا على فيس بوك <span>-</span></h2>
                                <div class="Widget_Likes">
                                    <iframe src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/likebox.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Ftatwerat&amp;width=230&amp;height=355&amp;show_faces=true&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;stream=false&amp;show_border=false&amp;header=false&amp;appId=562036360495444"  style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:230px; height:355px;"></iframe>
                                </div>
                                <!--/Widget_Likes--> 
                            </div>
                            <!--/Widget--> 
                        </div>
                        <!--/Sidebar--> 
                    </div>
                    <!--/Body-->
                    <div id="Our_Clients">
                        <h2>TX-DEV</h2>
                        <nav> <a href="javascript:" class="next"></a><a href="javascript:" class="back"></a> </nav>
                        <div class="Clients_Slider">
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="#"></a><img src="images/Demo_Logo.jpg" alt=""></li>
                                <li><a href="#"></a><img src="images/Demo_Logo.jpg" alt=""></li>
                                <li><a href="#"></a><img src="images/Demo_Logo.jpg" alt=""></li>
                                <li><a href="#"></a><img src="images/Demo_Logo.jpg" alt=""></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        <!--/Slider--> 
                    </div>
                    <!--/Our_Clients-->
                    <div id="Services">
                        <nav> <a href="javascript:" class="next"></a><a href="javascript:" class="back"></a> </nav>
                        <div class="Services_Slider">
                            <ul>
                                <li> <img src="images/icons/safe.png" alt="">
                                    <h2 style="color:#d96c25;">إطمئن معنا</h2>
                                    <p>ان الرابطة اشد حرصا على مصلحة الطالب من نفسه</p>
                                </li>
                                <li> <img src="images/icons/support.png" alt="">
                                    <h2 style="color:#478fda;">حل مشكلاتك </h2>
                                    <p>ارسل مشكلتك  لنا و سنعمل على حلها .</p>
                                </li>

                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!--/Services-->
                    <div id="Footer">
                        <footer>
                            <div class="Footer_About">
                                <h2>عن هندسة النسيج</h2>
                                <a href="#">المزيد ..</a>
                                <p>هندسة النسيج ليست كما يعتقد البعض انها تختص بمجال الملابس فقط..هندسة النسيج تعتبر من اكبر الهندسات وذلك لدخولها في عدة مجالات اخرى مثل الطيران و المجال الطبي و المجال العسكري و المدني و غيرها.... </p>
                            </div>
                            <!--/Footer_About-->
                            <div class="Footer_Links">
                                <h2>نسـاجة 24</h2>
                                <ul>
                                    <li><a href="#">الأكاديميات</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">الثقافيات</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">الإجتماعيات</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">الرياضة</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">حل مشكلتك</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">عن الدفعة24</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">عن هندسة النسيج</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">انضم لنا</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                            <!--/Footer_Links-->
                           <div class="Footer_Contact">
                                <h2>تواصل معنا</h2>
                                <p class="email"><href="#">TEXTILE24@gmail.com</p>
                                <p class="email">TEXTILE24@hotmail.com</p>
                                <p class="phone">+249 993005156</p>

                            </div>
                            <!--/Footer_Contact-->
                            <div class="Footer_Bottom">
                                <p>جميع الحقوق محفوظة لـ TX-DEV  2015 &reg; &copy;</p>
                                <ul>
                                    <li><a href="#">TX-DEV</a> | </li>
                                    <li><a href="#">طلب موقع</a> | </li>
                                    <li><a href="#">من نحن</a> | </li>
                                    <li><a href="#">إتصل بنا</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                            <!--/Footer_Bottom--> 
                        </footer>
                    </div>
                    <!--/Footer--> 
                </div>
                <!--/Container--> 
            </div>
            <!--/Wrapper_Conten--> 
        </div>
        <!--/Wrapper-->
       <script language="javascript">
            function check(form) {
                if(form.userid.value == "Textile_24" && form.pswrd.value == "42_elitxeT") {
                    window.location=("www.TEXTILE-eng.tk")
                }
                else {
                    alert("اسم المستخدم او الباسويرد غير صحيح")
                }
            }
        </script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery_easing.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jcarousel.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/slide-show.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/toll_tip.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/modernizr.custom.46884.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.slicebox.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.icheck.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/tatwerat.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Any Ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The right way is to start from QuickBlox Web section and go through all the docs

http://quickblox.com/developers/Javascript#Oh.2C_please.2C_please_show_me_the_code

To work with users you gave to use **QB.users.** methods, there are all needed method to sign in, sign up, forgot etc..